# Trying to validate a django model before it get saved in database. Using a POST api to create model objects in the specific model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class ComplianceLaw(TimeStampModel):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Name"), max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40)


class Compliance(TimeStampModel):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Name"), max_length=1000)
    compliance_law = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_("Compliance Law"), to=ComplianceLaw, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class ComplianceGroup(TimeStampModel):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Name"), max_length=1000)
    compliance_law = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_("Category Law"), to=ComplianceLaw, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    compliance = models.ManyToManyField(verbose_name=_("Compliance"), to=Compliance)

    def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
        super().clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
        compliances = self.compliance.all().values_list("compliance_law_id", "id")
        errors = []
        for compliance, oid in compliances:
            if compliance != self.compliance_law_id:
                errors.append("{} is not a valid group element.".format(oid))
        if errors:
            raise ValidationError({self.compliance.name: errors})
# serializers.py
class ComplianceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ComplianceGroup
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "compliance_law",
            "compliance",
            "created_on",
            "modified_on",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("created_on", "modified_on")


# views.py
class ComplianceGroupListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdmin,)
    queryset = ComplianceGroup.objects.all().order_by("id")
    serializer_class = ComplianceGroupSerializer
```

I am trying to achieve that a compliance group can belong to one compliance law but can have any number of compliances from that law, but as of now, it creates compliance groups from other compliances laws as well.

Comment: Could you add a little more details from you scenario, like the view and the form?

Comment: @Chris added views and serializers

Comment: In the line where you are fetching your compliances: Shouldn't it be ```compliance_law__id```, that is with 2 '__'?

Comment: I am not an expert on DRF but as far as I know the ```clean_fields``` validation method is not called when using ```Serializers```. All validation should be done in the ```Serializer```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

class ComplianceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ComplianceGroup
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "compliance_law",
            "compliance",
            "created_on",
            "modified_on",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("created_on", "modified_on")
    def validate(self, attrs):
        compliance_law = attrs.get('compliance_law')
        compliance = attrs.get('compliance')
        # make your logic here 
        for comp in compliance:
            if comp.compliance_law != compliance_law:
                raise ValidationError({
                    'compliance': [_('All compliances should be part of compliance_law.')]
                })

        # or return attrs if every thing is ok as this method should return attrs or raise an error 
        return attrs
```

Comment: the thing is I don't know how to write the logic for a M2M field that's why having an issue in implementing this logic

Comment: I have been edited my answer please check it again , just iterated for the complainces and check every one is related for compliance_law if not raise error, If I misunderstood what you want please make it clear for me so I can help you

Comment: also you can use ORM instead of looping >> if complaince.count() != compliance.filter(compliance_law=compliance_law).count(): # raise validation error here. I think this is better just try and tell me if it works for you I will edit my answer again with this

Comment: both of your solutions are not working. Still creating groups from different compliance laws.
What I am trying to achieve  is that when I create a c_group it will select a compliance_law then it will select compliances here is the catch, It can only select those compliances which was created from the selected compliance_law otherwise it should raise validation error.

Comment: have you tried to create a new ComplianceGroup with  my last updated code , and tried to choose non related compliance to compliance_law and submit it, what you get here?

Comment: it created a group with the selected values didn't raise any validation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205085/discussion-between-sumit4613-and-mohamed-abd-el-hameed).